# How to check the null in efficient way

Tags: java

I have this following line of Java code, how to rewrite in efficient way?

```
.b(a!=null ? a.getValue() : null)
```

Comment: Nothing inefficient about this. But do you really want to call `b()` with a null value?

Comment: This is as efficient as it gets, leave it alone.

Comment: What do you mean with "efficient"?

Comment: Optional.ofNullable( a ).map( a-> a.getValue ).orElse( NullPointerException::new );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is as efficient as you can get (AFAIK).  And it is actually *more efficient than it appears* ... assuming that the code gets JIT compiled<sup>1</sup>.

The call `a.getValue()` has an implicit check that `a` is not `null`.  So, the JIT compiler is going to simplify this (pseudo-code) from

```
   if a != null then 
       if a != null then
           a.getValue()
       else
           throw NPE
   else
       null
```

to

```
   if a != null then 
       a.getValue() // NPE not possible
   else
       null
```

---

<sup>1 - And if not, we can say that the code has not been run often enough for the performance to be significant.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If the variable an is nullable, you can use the `Optional` class. Assuming 'a' is an `Optional` itself, you may rewrite the code as follows:

```
.b(a.map(A::getValue).orElse(null))
```

Comment: And ... that will probably be substantially >less< efficient.  (Unless the JIT compiler gets really smart.)